# thunderbird not starting when clicking on icon

Tags: unity, icons, thunderbird

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on a ThinkPad-T430s.  64bit version. Up to date.

I have the icon for Thunderbird in my dock, where I launch the program.
I have also tried launching it fromthe search bar, where I type in thunderbird.

Most of the time when I click on it, it takes a little bit to load, and then it runs fun.

Once in awhile, I will click on it, and it wil load, and then the loading stops and no Thinderbird.

I hae not seen any reasons as to why this might happen

The only way to fix it is to reboot the computer.

Can anyone suggest why this is happening, and how to correct it?

Thanks

Joseph

Comment: Try launching it from terminal, `thunderbird`and do post if there are any errors

Comment: I used the following command to launch thinderbird:   thunderbird

Comment: I get the following:    [1]+  Done                    thunderbird